# SVG fine in browsers but broken (just shows a black box) in Illustrator or InkScape

Tags: image, svg, graphics, vector-graphics, adobe-illustrator

I've got an issue with SVG files generated by a program. They validate fine, display fine in browsers and in OS X Preview, but display as a big black box in Illustrator or InkScape or various other programs.

I suspect there's something to do with transparency or a tag not being supported or something, but I don't really know what - and a cursory glance looks fine...

There are hundreds of these. I can write a script to correct them all but I don't know what to correct...!

[Original SVG](http://maxhunter.me/broken.svg)

[How it looks in Illustrator or InkScape](http://maxhunter.me/illustrator.png)

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an rgb**a** syntax for fill is not supported everywhere. Try using rgb values e.g. `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, hex colours e.g. `#ffffff` or named colours e.g. `white`.

You don't need the a anyway as your opacities are always 1 and if you did it would be more portable to specify a separate fill-opacity value.